# How to link a resouce to a backend api url dynamically in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I have a resource component like

```
<Resource name="words" list={Wordlist}/>
```

And I want it to access a backend api url dynamically generated like

```
/wordbooks/value_from_my_redux_store/words
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write logic like that inside a custom data provider.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html

You'd likely want to intercept the `words` resource and feed the fetch (or whatever) the uri you desire on that resource.